# How to tell Adobe Illustrator to use a font of a slightly different name?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I'm opening a PDF created with Adobe Illustrator CC in Adobe Illustrator CS6 and other than some features may not be available warning, it complains about a missing font:

> The font TrendRoughSlabOne is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.

However, I did purchase that font, but it shows up in the Illustrator Font menu as `Trend Rh Slab One`.

How can I instruct Illustrator to substitute and use this name variant instead?

Comment: Just so you know, a lot of design software have this functionality. If it happens with other software, you can try to find it. Fonts with same names have sometimes different "tags" you don't see or are slightly different variant, and software don't associate the name with the real font. That can happen sometimes. That's why fonts should always follow the editable files. That wasn't the problem you got but now you know and might want to make sure you save a copy of that new font with your editable files to not mix them up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Type > Find Font`

Click the original in the top pane, then choose the substitution in the bottom pane. Then click `Change All`.

Comment: I didn't know about that and actually never bothered to know about it cause I never had a file with that many fonts that I couldn't change manually and save but it's nice to know, thanks :) !